# What are the usecases of metaprogamming in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I have been coding Python applications for 5+ years.
During this time, I have not used metaprogamming.

Many books claim that Metaprogramming is one of the most complex and powerful approaches to programming in Python.

Can anyone please highlight the use cases of metaprogamming in Python?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by metaprogramming. Ever used a decorator? Poked an object's `__dict__`?

Comment: Yes. Is that Metaprogramming? I thought those were magic instance methods and metaprogamming was above classes.